# Cross multiply text in PHP

Tags: php

I have two excel sheets-

First Sheet Columns:

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE (containing M rows) ~700 rows  
A     B    C    D    E  
AA   BB   CC    DD   EE
```

Second Sheet Columns:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 (containing N rows) ~ 100 rows  
1     2    3    4
11    22   33   44
```

Final Result Set:

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  
A    B     C    D    E   1      2    3    4  
A    B     C    D    E   11    22    33   44  
AA   BB   CC   DD   EE   1      2     3    4  
AA   BB   CC   DD   EE   11    22    33    44
```

I want a resultant spreadsheet which will be a cross multiplication of the above two sheets: M X N rows and copy it back to csv/excel.

I am using PHP to cross join the two sheets. I have converted both the sheets in csv so my first sheet is csv1 and second is csv2.

```
<?php
$csv1 = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Book1.csv'));
$csv2 = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Book2.csv'));

$ans = array();

foreach ($csv1 as $key1) {
    foreach ($csv2 as $key2) {
        $ans[] = $key1 . ' ' . $key2;
    }
}

$fp = fopen('file.csv','w');

foreach($ans as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
?>
```

For some reason, this is not working. The server is not responding and the file is not populating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below. It will create a file named `output.csv`. For me you don't have to read them the way you read csv for you fill not edit a column. Why not just merge them and concatinate with it comma:

```
<?php
$csv1 = file('Book1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv2 = file('Book2.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$output = fopen('output.csv','w');

foreach ($csv1 as $value_csv1) {
    foreach ($csv2 as $value_csv2) {
        fwrite($output, $value_csv1 . ',' . $value_csv2 . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
?>
```